# What's wrong with this node.js/socket.io code that gives "missing name after the . operator"?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is the line that causes trouble.  It's node.js + socket.io on the backend and it shows an error in NetBeans.  It sends the message from the server, but the handle comes up undefined.

```
io.sockets.in(socket._chatroom).emit('broadcast_message', {message: message, handle: socket._handle});
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code so that it takes multiple lines. You'll have an easier time figuring out which `. operator` netbeans is talking about.